# Infinitesimal Calculus / Analysis - supremum and infimum question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

defined $R_+ = \{x ∈ R | x > 0\}$
for every non empty subset $B$ of $R_+$ we define $B^{-1} = \{b^{-1} : b∈B\}$
prove that if $B^{-1}$ is bounded above then $\inf (B) =(\sup B^{-1})^{-1}$ seems easy to show that:
if $B^{-1}$ is bounded it has supremum $S$.

$S\geq b^{-1}$ , for all $b^{-1} ∈ B^{-1}$ hence:

$S^{-1}\leq b$, for all $b ∈ B$. therefore $B$ has a lower bound.therefore $B$ has an infimum.

now is it enough to state that:
suppose that $S^{-1}$ is not the infimum; there exists a $b ∈ B$ such that $b<S^{-1}\Rightarrow$ there exists $b^{-1} > S$ and that contradicts the original statement.
what do you think?

Comment: I think that's indeed enough.